# ready function inside jsp and ready function in js file

Tags: jquery

I have a ready function inside my jsp and also a ready function inside my javascript. I am having some issues understanding in what order things are running.

Inside my jsp i have...

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() {
        var params = ({
            reportingManagerTitle : "<spring:message code='title.reportingManager'/>",
            launchButtonText: "<spring:message code='button.launch'/>"          
        });
    init(params);
    }); 
    </script>       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="resources/js/pages/login.js" />"></script>    
</head>
```

Then inside my javascript file I have ...

```
var reportingManagerTitle = null;
var launchButtonText = null;
$().ready(function() {
    // do something with reportingManagerTitle after page load
    alert(reportingManagerTitle );

    // so something with launchButtonText after page load
    alert(launchButtonText );
});

function init(params) { 
    reportingManagerTitle = params.reportingManagerTitle;
    launchButtonText = params.launchButtonText;
}
```

My problem is that both reportingManagerTitle and launchButtonText are undefined. I through the javascript in my js would run first and then the js in my external file. What am I doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use that `vars` outside of `init` function? If you are, you cant do that since they are the function's `vars` unless you declare em first outside of the function as globals. And dont forget either that might not help if you are trying to use em outside of `$().ready`. Check the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gyK2F/)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the declaration of the variables. They are declared at the top of the js files as globals

Comment: Now, you declared em as globals and you are using them inside another `$().ready` so that should work. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gyK2F/1/) There must be something else. Are you sure you dont have misspelling on var names or something?

Comment: Hmm ok. That is basically what I have done already. Funny thing is that my code worked on tomcat 6 but when I went to deploy on Websphere 6.1 it didn't work. I put break points on init and on the alert. The alert always ran first which  is why I thought my ordering might be out of whack.

Comment: Can you try `$(window).load` instead of `$().ready` inside both main document script and function ?

Comment: thanks for your help/. I'm so sorry. I've just worked out today the issue was to do with caching. My new jsp was not being deployed. Sorry to have wasted your time.